# Guardar un dato en una una tabla de sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, odbc

Tengo un dilema con un proyecto de página web que estoy haciendo. Verán, se trata de un registro de ciertos productos vendidos, creando tipo facturas, entonces necesito de un folio. El folio que se asignará por default a cada usuario será 1, el número se guardará en la tabla SVenta que contiene TODOS los datos de las ventas por usuarios, y al tener su primer registro en esa tabla comenzará el conteo 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... Pero existe la posibilidad de que constantemente ese Folio se actualice y es donde no se como hacerle. Pues si actualizan el folio de un usuario debe comenzar en ese número, guardarlo en la tabla SVenta y volver a contar de ahí. Todo ésto se hace desde un botón que guarda y actualiza el folio. 
El método que utilizo es:

```
 protected void CamFactura()
{
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=Conexion server;uid=sa;pwd=xxxx");
    DataTable dtr = new DataTable();
    OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SlpCode FROM Vendedores WHERE SlpName = '" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "'", cn); //Obtiene el ID del usuario que ingreso
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cm);
    da.Fill(dtr);
    cn.Open();
    DataRow fila1 = dtr.Rows[0];
    if (dtr.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        OdbcCommand cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT count(noFactura) FROM Factura WHERE SlpCode = '" + Convert.ToString(fila1["SlpCode"]) + "'", cn); //verifica primero si hay un registro en la tabla Factura (el campo 'noFactura' esta en null para todos)
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 0)//no se encontró registro
        {
            OdbcCommand cmd3 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT count(noFactura) FROM SVenta WHERE SlpCode = '" + Convert.ToString(fila1["SlpCode"]) + "'", cn); //verifica si se encontró registro dentro de la tabla SVenta
            int coun = Convert.ToInt32(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
            if (coun == 0)//no se encontró registro
            {
                label2.Text = "1"; //le da valor de 1 al folio, éste se guarda como el valor del primer registro
            }
            else //si hay registros
            {
                OdbcCommand cmdd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT (max(noFactura) +1) FROM SVenta WHERE SlpCode ='" + Convert.ToString(fila1["SlpCode"]) + "'", cn); //suma uno al último registro encontrado
                label2.Text = Convert.ToString(cmdd.ExecuteScalar()); //imprime el valor en el label y lo muestra 
            }
        }
        else //si se encontró un registro en la tabla Factura
        {
            OdbcCommand cmd4 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT (max(noFactura) +1) FROM Factura WHERE SlpCode ='" + Convert.ToString(fila1["SlpCode"]) + "'", cn); //Le suma uno al valor que se encuentra en la tabla
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd4.ExecuteScalar()); //lo imprime en el label
            int coun = Convert.ToInt32(cmd4.ExecuteScalar()); //¿De qué manera le digo que me guarde el folio y después tome el de la tabla SVenta
            if (coun == 1)
            {
                 //Aquí no se cómo hacer para que guarde ese número y comience a contar de nuevo por el último registro de la tabla SVenta
            }
        }
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

También identificar cuando se actualiza su número de folio y volver a hacer el mismo proceso.

EJEMPLO:
Usuario1 con Folio 1 en su primer registro
//actualizan a Usuario1 con Folio 1234
Usuario1 con Folio 1235 en su último registro
//en la tabla SVenta se guardan consecutivamente los Folios

PROBLEMA:
El Código funciona cuando en la tabla FACTURA columna noFactura esta null, cuando se agrega un folio cual sea lo guarda la primera vez, pero no vuelve a tomar el último registro, porque no eh colocado el código que diga que lo haga, ya que no se de qué manera hacerlo. 
También, únicamente tomaría la primera actualización del FOLIO, pero no las demás, que es lo que yo quiero.

Comment: Hola Elizabeth. que no contestamos esta pregunta ya?

Comment: No, la situación es diferente, pues aquí hablo de actualizaciones constantes del Folio, pero no se cómo acomodar mi método para que reconozca la actualización y cuente desde ahí, que la tabla SVenta sirva simplemente para guardar.

Comment: ok ok.. recordaba el escenario por eso preguntaba... pero el problema como esta explicado aca me parecio exactamente el mismo...

Comment: Como primera nota, te diria que ejecutar dos veces seguidas cmd4 esta mal...

Comment: Igual no logro entender tu escenario.. podrias poner un ejemplo? porque por lo que pones en el codigo, la logica es la que escribiste...

Comment: Espero entenderme mejor, ya actualice

Comment: porque directamente no tenes una tabla con el ultimo numero usado para cada usuario y listo? me parece que estas complicando mucho la logica de algo mas simple...

Comment: Al campo de numero de folio ponle identity en la tabla de la base de datos, de esta forma cada que insertes un registro tu no le especificas el número, sino que la misma base de datos lo genera auto incrementando el ultimo generado.